# why findnext on beautifulsoup return different result in every running

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i try to get date release song from genius page

```
# Scrape lyrics from a Genius.com song URL
def scrape_song_lyrics(url_song_):
page = requests.get(url_song_)
html = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#get date release
temp = html.find(text="Release Date")
if temp is not None:
  date = temp.find_next()
  print(url_song_)
  print(temp)
  print(date)
  year = re.findall("([0-9]{4})",str(date))[0]
  print(year)
  lyrics = html.find('div', class_='lyrics').get_text()
  #remove identifiers like chorus, verse, etc
  lyrics = re.sub(r'[\(\[].*?[\)\]]', '', lyrics)
  #remove empty lines
  lyrics = os.linesep.join([s for s in lyrics.splitlines() if s])
  
  return year, lyrics
else:
  return None, None
```

but it return different result each running.
the correct result is:

```
https://genius.com/Justin-bieber-love-yourself-lyrics
Release Date
<span class="metadata_unit-info metadata_unit-info--text_only">November 13, 2015</span>
2015
```

but sometimes it return:

```
https://genius.com/Justin-bieber-love-yourself-lyrics
Release Date
<div class="HeaderMetadata__Section-sc-1p42fnf-2 bVnuPE"><div class="HeaderMetadata__ViewCredits-sc- 
1p42fnf-5 gBcnuN"><a class="Link-h3isu4-0 cGlaEJ" font-weight="light" href="#song-info">View All 
Credits<!-- --> <span class="InlineSvg__Wrapper-b788hd-0 jZbnyS"><svg viewbox="0 0 6.6 16"><path 
d="M1.6 8.8l.6-.6 1 1 .5.7V6H0v-.8h4.5v4.6l.5-.6 1-1 .6.5L4 11.3 1.6 8.8z"></path></svg></span></a> 
</div></div>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
```

the **.find_next()** method return different result

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, there are two versions of the page. This script should work with both of them and print the release date of the song:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://genius.com/Justin-bieber-love-yourself-lyrics'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

tag = soup.select_one('p:contains("Release Date"), span:contains("Release Date")')
release_date = tag.parent.text.replace('Release Date', '').strip()

print(release_date)
```

Prints:

```
November 13, 2015
```